# Community wiki status lost on migration

Tags: bug, migration, community-wiki

It seems like CW answers revert to non-CW once they are migrated.

[This answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4829144/65548) was given on [mo], and when I wrote it I ticked the "community wiki" checkbox. However, when the question was migrated to [math.se], it wasn't community wiki anymore until I edited it and ticked the box again.

Comment: Not a bug, that's just how migration works. Amazing enough, nobody asked to change it yet, so you can change this question to feature request asking to change it (i.e. title like "Don't change the community wiki status upon migration") and I'll reopen.

Comment: I rather prefer as it is now just because, in my case, it is more probable I do not want to keep the answer CW after the migration. (In the case I want it to be a CW, I just edit it.)

Comment: @apaderno What is the reason, if you wish to expand? It seems unusual to me to want the same answer to be CW on one site of the network but not on another.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Because my decision to make my answer CW could depend from the site where the question was asked. If the answer was instead automatically made CW, I would like to have the option to decide myself to make the answer CW.